# Not able to install openssh in amazon aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install openssh in aws 54  server. But it is not installed.

cygwin registry errors.that problem resolved. But not able to install.
I'm trying deploy application in AWS server using ant script. so i need openssh need to install. is there any other way to deploy in AWS uisng ant script

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Please try one of the other Q&A sites dedicated to system administration (etcetera) questions.  Certainly, this has absolutely nothing to do with Java.

Comment: are you trying to used openssh to connect to your aws server, or are you installing openssh on your instance?  provide more details on the system setup.